# curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d to PHP

Tags: php, curl

I need to make a curl request, I have this line "curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d" and need to "translate" to PHP curl. The problem is I don't know what the "-X", "-H" and "-d" mean.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: '. strlen($itemJson))
    );
```

I tried something like that on header (`$itemJson` is a JSON string) but I got error 400.

I think I'm doing the request in a wrong way. Can anybody help me?

Comment: -X means the method type. -H means headers, and -d means data tat will be sent with the request.

Comment: Thanks! I think the request is right, I'll check the data.

Comment: To convert Curl command to PHP https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try as below

```
$data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://somedomain.com/test.php');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you!.. That's it, I was sending the POST to an old url.