# Converting bash curl function to php curl functionality

Tags: php, bash, curl

I am doing this through bash:

```
curl -X POST myapp.dev/api/v1/clients -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"name":"Client","contact":{"email":"test@gmail.com"}}' -H "X-Ninja-Token: SDFsdfsd4s5d445fs4d55sd54f4s5" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"
```

and it works fine, but I want to do the same through php with curl. How this curl fuction should look like in php? I actually tried lots of variants, but I did not get the right result so far.

Comment: did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13010433/3612353) ?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned I tried a few variants, but none of them worked. It might be that I am failing at sending the token.

Comment: Your token should be as another element in array `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

Comment: I figured out my mistake. Instead of curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);   for some reasons I passed these values as    'Content-Type=> application/json',

Comment: Does it fix your problem?)